# Synchronising paragraph placement using reladpar/reledmac

Tags: languages, double-sided, reledmac, reledpar

I am typesetting two language document, where one of the languages is placed only on odd pages and another only on even. The problem is the corresponding paragraphs should strictly start on the same height in single opening, no matter how long the paragraph is. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Scale=1.6]{TriodionUnicode}
    \newfontfamily\germanfont[Language=German, Scale=1.5]{MonomakhUnicode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{churchslavonic}
    \setotherlanguage{german}
    
\usepackage{churchslavonic}

\usepackage[a5paper, top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bindingoffset=0.25cm, headsep=0.7em, footskip=1.5em]{geometry}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\numberlinefalse

\newcommand{\vo}[1]{\cuKinovar{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mo}[1]{{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\co}[1]{\centerline{\cuKinovar{\footnotesize{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\vode}[1]{\cuKinovar{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mode}[1]{{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\centerline{\cuKinovar{\footnotesize{#1}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\setstretch{1.1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \input{bascs2.tex}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    
        \beginnumbering
            \input{basde2.tex}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages

\end{document}
```

But the problem is I can not achieve proper alignment of paragraphs, they are not synchronized. Here is the screenshot of first two pages, where the first few paragraphs are perfectly synchronized as I want them to be:

[image: Beginning of the document]

But at the last line of the first page I already start encountering synchronization issues. Near to the end of document it goes completely wrong:

[image: End of the document]

I have checked markup and paragraph counts in both languages - all is perfectly same. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! (1) You might improve your example: As it stands, it doesn't exhibit the problematic behavior that you describe, because all paragraphs are 1 line long, so they are trivially **always aligned** at the same height as their counterpart. (2) I added more lines of text on the first left hand paragraph and compiled your example. The result: Each paragraph was horizontally synchronized with its translation. Isn't this precisely your desired result?

Comment: For clarity's sake, it may also help to add a screengrab of your current result vs. the desired result :)

Comment: Yes, of course. I will add some screenshots now.

Comment: it looks as if the different font sizes and line distances confuse the sync. But without  a complete example it is not possible to say what exactly goes wrong. Btw: Font size commands like \footnotesize do not take an argument, they are switches.